# Need help with AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am developing an ASP.NET based website.

In a Master Page, I have a UL list, which is used to display links (akin to left nav). As of now, upon click of each li, the user is taken to respective page.

The problem is, when user is redirected to another page, the master page is also getting reloaded, as a result of which, the clicked-link is not highlighted. (All the UL is in a query accordion control).

Hence, I plan to use AJAX - i.e. whenever a user clicks a link in an accordion control, the corresponding page contents should be loaded and displayed in a place holder, so that the link is highlighted and user is aware of the current page info.

**Please advise me as to how to achieve this (either thru' ASP.NET AJAX or Javascript AJAX)**

The code in master page is as below:

script type="text/javascript">

```
// well all the DOM is written in the page and all elements are available do:
$(document).ready(function() {

    // for each <a> tag bind the event click and now do:     
    $("a").click(function() {

        // 1st. remove all selected
        $("a.selected").removeClass("selected");

        // 2nd. assign selected to this clicked element only
        $(this).addClass("selected");

        // 3rd. let's return true so the <a> tag can jump to the href
        return true;
    });
});
```

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
```

Haemostasis Kits

- ">Coaliza Anti-Cardiolipin
- ">Coamatic Antithrombin
- ">Coamtic LR-Antithrombin
- ">Coatest APC Resistance
- ">Coatest APC Resistance V
- ">Coatest APC Resistance V S
- ">V-DEF Plasma
- ">Coaset Factor VII
- ">Coamatic Factor VIII
- ">Coatest SP FVIII
- ">Coatest SP4 FVIII
- ">Coatest Heparin
- ">Coatest LMW Heparin/Heparin
- ">Coamatic Heparin
- ">Coamatic Plasmin Inhibitor
- ">Coamatic Plasminogen
- ">Coamatic Protein C
- ">Coalisa Protein S Free

Calibrators & Controls

- ">Calibration Plasma LMW Heparin
- ">Coatest APC Res. Contr. Plasma Lev.1
- ">Coatest APC Res. Contr. Plasma Lev.2
- ">Control Plasma LMW Heparin

Test 1

Chromogenic Substrates

- S-2222

Test 3

Bio Reagents

- Antithrombin 10 IU
- ">Cardio-FABP

Test 4

**To have a feel of page, please visit:**
http://www.murandmur.in/test2/Products/products-exclusive.aspx

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The way I went about doing more-or-less the same thing is to build a web service (or page method), which gets the body HTML from the DB and returns it (as a simple text string). This takes care of the server-side.
On the client side, use jQuery (which you use anyway) to make ajax calls to the web service.
I used these two links as reference when I was starting out:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx

Hope this points you in the right direction.